# shadowy images question

Tags: javascript

http://themeforest.net/item/converge-the-best-premium-drupal-theme/full_screen_preview/405072

I am trying to make a d7 version of this slider.  I have enabled KWICKS VIEWS but I cannot seem to get a 3d effect, like it has here.  Does anyone know what kind of css this uses?  what i create and list class and enable it in VIEWS?

I used firebug to inspect but didnt see anything obvious.  THANK YOU

--newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using a transparent png to fade out the background and give that box shadow type effect on the right.  Look at class fade-bg and you'll see how.